# copy files after a user specified file name

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to copy files after a user specified file name. I have folder that updates every day with hundreds of files in it listed in numerical order with the format 4129_XXXX.txt. Where XXXX is the only number that changes for instance if 4129_0001.txt is the first file the next would be 4129_0002.txt and so on. I have a separate macro that pulls all the information I want from the txt files but I have to manually copy all the new incidents from the folder and save them into my directory to run my data sorting macro on them. I want to set it up so that I can simply type in the last incident and the macro pulls all the files after the user specified file and automatically copies them to my directory so I can run my data sorting macro. My code is below I have it set up where the user can type in the last incident seen on the data sorted macro excel sheet from the previous day. My goal was then to have the code pull all the files after the number the user typed in however my code simply continues to copy all the files in the folder. I could really use some help in solving this issue.

```
Sub sort_read()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Dim FileInFromFolder As Object
Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileContent As String
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myValue As Variant

myValue = InputBox("4129_XXXX.txt")
MyFolder = "C:\Users\Desktop\Logbook Source Files\master"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\myValue")
If MyFolder > myValue Then
    FromPath = MyFolder
    ToPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Logbook Source Files\Data"

    If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
        FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
    End If

    If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "You can find the files and subfolders from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath
End If

End Sub
```

Update Code-------

```
Dim Ret As Variant
Dim counter As Long
Dim endNumber As Long
Dim ToPath As String


Ret = Application.InputBox("Please enter the number", Type:=1)

If Ret = False Then Exit Sub
counter = Ret

'~~> Change Folder here
Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = "C:\Desktop\Logbook Source Files\master"
Dim aFile As String

aFile = Dir(FolderPath & "4129_" & counter & ".txt")
endNumber = 1370 '<~~ Set here till when the loop should run

Do While Len(aFile) > 0 Or counter < endNumber
        FromPath = FolderPath
        ToPath = "C:\Users\arvaldiv\Desktop\Logbook Source Files\Data"

        If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
            FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
        End If

        If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
            ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
        End If

        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

        If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
            MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
            Exit Sub


FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
MsgBox "You can find the files and subfolders from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath
End If


    If Len(aFile) > 0 Then Debug.Print aFile

    counter = counter + 1
    aFile = Dir(FolderPath & "4129_" & counter & ".txt")
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Haven't checked the code completely but `FolderPath = "C:\Desktop\Logbook Source Files\master"` should be `FolderPath = "C:\Desktop\Logbook Source Files\master\"`

Comment: Similarly `ToPath = "C:\Users\arvaldiv\Desktop\Logbook Source Files\Data\"` and then you can delete both the `If Right(... Then`. Also remove `FromPath` and `ToPath` from inside the loop. Keep it outside

Comment: I updated the below answer with updated code. You may have to refresh it to see it. Give it a try

Comment: your updated code works, Just a follow up question if i wanted to do the same with say the source folder being a zip file would I need to unzip the folder first then run this code to copy files from the unzipped folder to a new destination folder?

Comment: No. You can directly unzip the files into the new folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** It is prettry simple actually. Since `4129_` is constant, do not ask for that from the user. Ask for the number that changes..

**2.** Instead of just using `InputBox`, use `Application.InputBox` with `Type:=1`. You may read about it in [Application.InputBox method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox). This way you can restrict what the user is typing in the InputBox.

Here is a sample (**Untested**) of how to pull files after a specific number

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret As Variant
    Dim counter As Long

    Ret = Application.InputBox("Please enter the number", Type:=1)

    If Ret = False Then Exit Sub

    counter = Ret

    '~~> Change Folder here
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = "C:\MyFolder\"
    Dim aFile As String

    aFile = Dir(FolderPath & "4129_" & counter & ".txt")

    Do While Len(aFile) > 0

        '
        'Do what you want to do with that file
        '

        'Debug.Print aFile

        counter = counter + 1
        aFile = Dir(FolderPath & "4129_" & counter & ".txt")
    Loop
End Sub
```

**Note**: The above will break the loop if the numbers are not continous in the folder. For example, you want to start with 131 and you have `4129_131.txt, 4129_132.txt, 4129_135.txt, 4129_136.txt`. The code will stop at 132.

For example, let's say user wants to start at `131`. Then this loop will stop at `150`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret As Variant
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim endNumber As Long

    Ret = Application.InputBox("Please enter the number", Type:=1)

    If Ret = False Then Exit Sub

    counter = Ret

    '~~> Change Folder here
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = "C:\MyFolder\"
    Dim aFile As String

    aFile = Dir(FolderPath & "4129_" & counter & ".txt")
    endNumber = 151 '<~~ Set here till when the loop should run

    Do While Len(aFile) > 0 Or counter < endNumber

        '
        'Do what you want to do with that file
        '

        If Len(aFile) > 0 Then Debug.Print aFile

        counter = counter + 1
        aFile = Dir(FolderPath & "4129_" & counter & ".txt")
    Loop
End Sub
```

**Updated Post OP Comments**

Is this what you are trying to do? (**Untested**). I am assuming that the `ToPath` exists.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret As Variant
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim endNumber As Long

    Ret = Application.InputBox("Please enter the number", Type:=1)

    If Ret = False Then Exit Sub
    counter = Ret

    '~~> Change Folder here
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = "C:\Desktop\Logbook Source Files\master\"
    Dim ToPath As String: ToPath = "C:\Users\arvaldiv\Desktop\Logbook Source Files\Data\"
    Dim aFile As String

    aFile = Dir(FolderPath & "4129_" & counter & ".txt")
    endNumber = 1370 '<~~ Set here till when the loop should run

    Do While Len(aFile) > 0 Or counter < endNumber
        If Len(aFile) > 0 Then FileCopy FolderPath & aFile, ToPath & aFile

        counter = counter + 1
        aFile = Dir(FolderPath & "4129_" & counter & ".txt")
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code and added my portion that copies from "FolderPath" to "ToPath" the code runs without errors however it does not actually copy any files to the designated path

Comment: Please updated your question with the code that you are trying